# How to connect to SSH shell using Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, ssh

I was having remote machine configured with ssh shell and i need to automate it with jenkins.
but when i try to connect with ssh it is asking for password and i can't enter with the jenkins and ssh-keygen is already configured in my local machine.

What is the solution for this?

Here my jenkins is using a docker container. So, we cannot install sshpass and anyother commands because i cannot access to this docker file.

Comment: now i found a solution for this. we have to create a ssh key for this. store it in a jenkins docker container and copy the location

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@youripaddress -i /location/secret_ssh_file your command to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found a solution for this. we have to create a ssh key for this. store it in a jenkins docker container and copy the location.

command:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no yourusername@youripaddress -i /jenkinslocation/your_secret_ssh_file whoami(use any shell commands)
```